# Origin of the term "comrade matrices"

Tags: matrices, terminology

What is the origin of the term "comrade matrices"?

Why are they so called?

I was unable to find an answer elsewhere.

Comment: There seems to be no need to ask your question twice, or state that you could not find an answer. Keeping it short makes your question more likely to be well read.

Comment: I did some googlings, and came up with this. I suppose it is one of the cited papers could track back the origin of the name http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379584900776

Comment: "comrade" ? Maybe you want "companion matrix" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix ?

Answer (score 2):

The term "comrade matrix" is suggested in the paper [1]. The author mention that paper [2] coined the term "colleague" matrix for the Chebyshev polynomials, thus the author's more general construction is called "comrade".

The paper [1] proves that the comrade matrix has the same characteristic polynomial as the corresponding companion matrix. Also discussed several aspect that the comrade matrix and companion matrix are very similar.

The words "companion", "colleague", and "comrade" all means the resulting matrix is in close (and one-one) relationship with the corresponding monic polynomial. More precisely, the characteristic polynomial of the matrix generated from coefficients of the reference polynomial is the same as the reference polynomial in monic form.

Note that [1] gives two forms of colleague matrix, the second form is more common nowadays.

Just for a glance:

Colleague matrix original form

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-\beta_{1}}{\alpha_{1}} & \frac{\gamma_{2}^{1/2}}{\alpha_{1}} & 0 & \cdots &  & 0\\\
\frac{\gamma_{2}^{1/2}}{\alpha_{2}} & \frac{-\beta_{2}}{\alpha_{2}} & \frac{\gamma_{3}^{1/2}}{\alpha_{2}} & 0 &  & \vdots\\\
0 & \frac{\gamma_{3}^{1/2}}{\alpha_{3}} & \frac{-\beta_{3}}{\alpha_{3}} & \ddots & \ddots\\\
 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots\\\
 &  &  & \frac{\gamma_{n-1}^{1/2}}{\alpha_{n-1}} & -\frac{\beta_{n-1}}{\alpha_{n-1}} & \frac{\gamma_{n}^{1/2}}{\alpha_{n-1}}\\\
\frac{-a_{n}}{\alpha_{n}(\gamma_{2}\gamma_{3}\cdots\gamma_{n})^{1/2}} & \frac{-a_{n-1}}{\alpha_{n}(\gamma_{3}\gamma_{4}\cdots\gamma_{n})^{1/2}} & \cdots & \frac{-a_{3}}{\alpha_{n}(\gamma_{n-1}\gamma_{n})^{1/2}} & \frac{-a_{2}+\gamma_{n}}{\alpha_{n}\gamma_{n}^{1/2}} & \frac{-a_{1}-\beta_{n}}{\alpha_{n}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Colleague matrix alternative form

$$
A' = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{-\beta_{1}}{\alpha_{1}} & \frac{1}{\alpha_{1}} & 0 & \cdots &  & 0\\\
\frac{\gamma_{2}}{\alpha_{2}} & \frac{-\beta_{2}}{\alpha_{2}} & \frac{1}{\alpha_{2}} & 0 &  & \vdots\\\
0 & \frac{\gamma_{3}}{\alpha_{3}} & \frac{-\beta_{3}}{\alpha_{3}} & \ddots & \ddots\\\
 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots\\\
 &  &  & \frac{\gamma_{n-1}}{\alpha_{n-1}} & \frac{-\beta_{n-1}}{\alpha_{n-1}} & \frac{1}{\alpha_{n-1}}\\\
\frac{-a_{n}}{\alpha_{n}} & \frac{-a_{n-1}}{\alpha_{n}} & \cdots & \frac{-a_{3}}{\alpha_{n}} & \frac{-a_{2}+\gamma_{n}}{\alpha_{n}} & \frac{-a_{1}-\beta_{n}}{\alpha_{n}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Companion Matrix

$$
C=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\\
\vdots & 0 & 1 & \ddots & \vdots\\\
 &  & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\\\
-a_{n} & -a_{n-1} & \cdots & -a_{2} & -a_{1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

[1] Barnett, Stephen. 1975. “A Companion Matrix Analogue for Orthogonal Polynomials.” Linear Algebra and Its Applications 12 (3): 197–202. https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(75)90041-5.

[2] Good, I. J. 1961. “THE COLLEAGUE MATRIX, A CHEBYSHEV ANALOGUE OF THE COMPANION MATRIX.” The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics 12 (1): 61–68. https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/12.1.61.